# Permissions of ControlMaster directory

Tags: permissions, ssh

The `ControlMaster` feature of `ssh` allows to use the same channel for multiple `ssh`-commands, see e.g. [How can I maintain open ssh connection and use it from shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218272/how-can-i-maintain-open-ssh-connection-and-use-it-from-shell-scripts)

To use `ControlMaster`, I added these lines to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host example.com
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
  ControlPersist 5m
```

When I run `ssh example.com`, I get the following error:

```
$ ssh example.com
bind: No such file or directory
unix_listener: cannot bind to path: /home/peter/.ssh/sockets/peter@example.com-22.O2cv7vtsgMAFCav7
```

To fix this, I can run `mkdir ~/.ssh/sockets`:

```
$ mkdir ~/.ssh/sockets
$ ll ~/.ssh/sockets
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 peter peter 4096 Dec 28 17:51 ./
drwx------ 3 peter peter 4096 Dec 28 17:51 ../
```

As you can see, the directory `~/.ssh/sockets` has permissions `rwxrwxr-w`. **What should be the permissions of `~/.ssh/sockets`? Should `sockets` even be in `~/.ssh`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your `sockets` directory anywhere you like (as long as you have the appropriate rights to write there) but putting it inside the `.ssh` seems to me the more sensible idea (except in some very rare specific cases like I had once: pathname was too long)

Since `.ssh` should already be something like `drwx------`, the rights of `.ssh/sockets` could be the same or more liberal, this will have no impact.

<s>But I do not think this is your problem. Your error message is not consistent with your configuration file. The config file has a `@` in the `ControlPath` (and it is ok) but in the error message you do not have one.</s>

When testing, make sure first to kill all running `ssh` instances to the given host, as some may persist per your configuration and then if you change it you may not get the expected behavior.

<s>PS: please use `example.com` when you need a dummy hostname for documentation purposes</s>

Answer (score 2):

Create the directory into which you will be creating the unix sockets, as in OP, if you are using `ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p`, then use the command:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh/sockets
```

EDIT: possibly the directory doesn't exist.